# NGUI label issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ngui

I am new for NGUI. I have some problem.

use script add component to gameobject but show the warning. Use NGUI BMFont but it change to unity default font type.

"dynamic fonts suffer from issues in Unity itself where your characters may disappear, get garbled, or just not show at times. Use this feature at your own risk."

script : gameobject.AddComponent();

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYneG.png)

NGUI 3.8.0
Unity 4.6.5f1

Comment: script : gameobject.AddComponent<UIlabel>();

Comment: Why are you still using NGUI?The new Unity UI is not bad....

Comment: my projects are used ngui.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug from NGUI itself. Create a NGUI font Drag and Drop in the component and check if it works.